# Set initial model value for an angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive:

```
<div class="my-switch-on-off" 
     data-caption="Back" 
     data-section="frames" 
     data-module="back"
     >
</div>
```

And its template is a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="switch"
  ng-model="isActive"
  ngTrueValue="true"
  ngFalseValue="false"
  ng-change="toggleVisibility(section, module)"
/>
```

This directive is used around 10 times. All the checkboxes are not checked. I want to have a condition in my link function so I can have some of them checked. What is the right way to do that? Should I access the model and change its value or should I make the checkbox checked using jQuery lite? My directive is like:

```
angular.directive("mySwitchOnOff", [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: "C",
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: "template.html",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        return scope.toggleVisibility = function(section, module) {

        };
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

**Update, jsfiddle thx to @deitch**
What I want is when the data-section=`extensions` the checkbox of the template to be checked
http://jsfiddle.net/m0q28vjc/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh definitely set the value of the ng-model in the scope.

In your directive

```
angular.directive("mySwitchOnOff", [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: "C",
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: "template.html",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // set the value of toggled based on attrs
        scope.isActive = attrs.section === "extensions";
        return scope.toggleVisibility = function(section, module) {

        };
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Here is a fiddle with the correct structure

http://jsfiddle.net/m0q28vjc/4/

Comment: Sorry, my description was wrong, I saw the template of the directive and not the directive

Comment: @Avraam I am a little confused. Happy to modify my answer to better address the question, if you can clarify the question a bit more?

Comment: I tried they way you suggested me but `attrs["dataInitialChecked"]` and scope.isActive are `undefined`. Any idea why?

Comment: Move it into a fiddle, show me, we will fix it. But instead of `templateUrl` in the directive, use `template` so it is inline, makes it easier in jsfiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65437/discussion-between-avraam-and-deitch).